# Sugarcrm changing color of checkbox when ticked

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a questionnaire setup in SugarCRM. I would like to change color of label when the checkbox is ticked. I added following custom code:

```
'customCode' => '<span style="color: red">{$fields.interest_c.value}</span>',
```

But all i get is a 1 or a 0 in red color.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it like this:

```
'customCode' => '<input type="checkbox" id="interest_c" name="do_not_call" value="{$fields. interest_c.value}" title="" tabindex="0">'
```

and set the class for your color using the same accessor.

Comment: I am adding that to the detailviewdefs.php in the custom/modules/Leads/metadata directory. But I get an error on that line when i add it in.